# How to optimize regex expression to check text containing anchor tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a working regex to check text with only anchor tag in it but it is taking too much time to give result. Where do I need to do change in expression to optimize it?

The regex is working fine when there is only one anchor tag in it but not when there are multiple anchor tags and test string is wrong as per regex.

Below is my regex

```
/^([^<]*(<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>)*)*$/g
```

```
True :: /^([^<]*(<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>))/g.test('Test a <a href="https://www.google.com">test</a> hgygiuu dfgdfg')
False ::/^([^<]*(<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>))/g.test('Test a <a href="https://www.google.com">test</a> hgygiuu dfgdfg <b') //due to non matching '<b'
True :: /^([^<]*(<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>))/g.test('Test a <a href="https://www.google.com">test</a> hgygiuu dfgdfg Test a <a href="https://www.google.com">test</a> hgygiuu dfgdfg')
False (very slow) :: /^([^<]*(<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>))/g.test('Test a hyperlink with long text <a href="https://www.google.com">test</a> hgygiuu dfgdfg Test a <a href="https://www.google.com">test</a> hgygiuu dfgdfg <span')
```

Comment: Can you show how you're using the regex, describe what you're trying to do? Since you're already in Javascript, you can probably parse the string as an element instead, which would be far more elegant (and quicker) than using a regex

Comment: I have updated my question with some examples. I am trying to prevent injection(s) and just want to keep <a> tag which should only contains 'href' in it and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to verify that the input text can be *concatenated* with some HTML. If you can change the location that the input text is inserted so that it's inserted *on its own*, rather than as part of a larger HTML string, verification will be much easier.

For example, instead of

```
html += inputStr
```

do something like

```
html += '<div class="input-container"></div>';
```

and then, after the HTML is inserted into the document, assign to the `innerHTML` of that `.input-container`:

```
document.querySelector('.input-container').innerHTML = inputStr;
```

This will ensure that non-matching or incompleted tags simply get *ignored*, rather than causing problems. As you can see in the following snippet, despite the fact that the inner DOM string would *appear* to have been set to `foo<b` plus `>bar`, the `<b` part gets completely ignored because it's not a well-formed tag, and the `>` in `>bar` gets interpreted as a *text bracket*, not a part of a tag.

```js
container.innerHTML = 'foo<b';
container.innerHTML += '>bar';
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

If you use this method to insert the input string, validating the input gets a *lot* easier. All you have to do is parse the input string as an element, and check that the only tags the element contains are `<a>`s with `href`s:

```js
const verify = (str) => {
  const { body } = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
  return [...body.children].every(
    child => child.tagName === 'A' && child.hasAttribute('href') && child.attributes.length === 1
  );
};

console.log(
  verify('foo'),
  verify('foo <a href="link">link</a>'),
  verify('foo <a href="link" onclick="evil">link</a>')
);
```

Best to avoid trying to parse HTML with regular expressions when possible.

Make sure to do this in an environment *you* control (like in Node), not just on the client, since you can't trust any verification done on the client.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below regex. I hope it will helps you.

```
/^\<a.*\>.*\<\/a\>/
```